# flash + phone camera

Tags: iphone, android, flash, red5

for website that embed flash to capture camera (red5..etc). may i know is there any handset that currently support flash and can used to capture image from handset camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an iPhone.  No Flash support.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTC Hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htc_hero) reputedly has Flash. However, this is not part of standard Android, and I have no idea if it can access the camera in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, we can access the device camera using flash AIR application.
Recently I tested that and got good output.
I dont know about the iPhones, I tested on android device HTC Desire HD.